# What is the cost of finding a node in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always save the result of the `find()` in order to avoid multiple sub tree traversal if I need the value several times:

```
var $a_bar = $('div.foo').find('a.bar');
$a_bar.removeClass(...);
// ... code here
$a_bar.bazz();
```

instead of

```
$('div.foo').find('a.bar').removeClass(...);
// ... code here
$('div.foo').find('a.bar').bazz();
```

I am wondering if it is not a micro-optimization... So what is the cost/complexity of finding a node in `JQuery`?

Answer (score 8):

You can test it on js perf : http://jsperf.com/
Just create a test and run it.

I have created a small test here : http://jsperf.com/jquery-find55

On my browser (firefox 18) :

- test 1 (i save the find result) scores at 7,074 operations by second
- test 2 (i don't save the find result) scores at 1,553 operations by second

So, yes, `find` is "slow" and it's definitively a good idea to store it in a variable.

Comment: +1 for elegance and advantages: others may benefit from it too, others may contribute to the results and you get performance across several browsers and their versions. excellent.

Comment: Ok, now its more like an answer with the specific test added.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be re-using variables multiple times, it is definitely a great idea to `cache` them like you are doing.

`.find()` traversing within the jQuery object you pass before it, so it only looks within what is already given, making it very fast.

```
var $mainElement = $('#whatever'),
    $innerLIs  = $mainElement.find('li'),
    $innerTDs  = $mainElement.find('td');

// Now that these are cached in memory, doing anything to them is very quick

$innerLIs.hide();
// etc etc
```

If we kept querying for them, it would have to look through the DOM each time. And once that was finished, it would be wrapping it in a jQuery object each time as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating the same thing several times - it's best practice to make a variable.

That way you're just manipulating rather than looking it up first each time.

I removed my statement about shortening the code a little - here's a [net-tuts article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/) about jQuery selectors and "right to left" thinking

Comment: That new code snippet is bad advice. jQuery selectors work from right to left, so you're performing multiple unnecessary lookups in the DOM. `$('.foo').find('.bar')` or `$('.bar', '.foo')` would be more efficient (and vastly so depending on the size of your DOM).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's selection is known to be costly, and then running `.find` is even more so. Caching the objects is definitely a good idea and is also stylistically advantageous from a DRY point of view.